# Integrate StackNavigator with TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

How do I combine StackNavigator and TabNavigator?

My following code works:

**index.android.js :**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator,TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


import TestComp1 from './src/components/TestComp1'
import TestComp2 from './src/components/TestComp2'
import TestComp3 from './src/components/TestComp3'
import TestComp4 from './src/components/TestComp4'
import TestComp5 from './src/components/TestComp5'

export default class myApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <MyApp />

    );
  }
}


const MyApp = StackNavigator({
  TestComp1: {screen:TestComp1},
  TestComp2: {screen:TestComp2}
});

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  TestComp3: {screen:TestComp3},
  TestComp4: {screen:TestComp4}
  TestComp5: {screen:TestComp5}
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => myApp);
```

This works only for StackNavigator. I want to keep the existing navigation and integrate TabNavigation. Now in `TestComp1` if I do the following:

**TestComp1 :**

```
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import { FooterTabs } from './routes/FooterTabs';

export default class HomePage extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    header: null
  };

  render() {
  return(
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.mainContent}>

        <Button
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('TestComp1', {name: 'Lucy'})}
              title="NewPage"
        />

        <FooterTabs />  //Page shows all StackNavigator screens if I add this

        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

And the **FooterTabs:**

```
import { StackNavigator, TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import TestComp3 from '../TestComp3';
import TestComp4 from '../TestComp4';
import TestComp5 from '../TestComp5';



export const FooterTabs = TabNavigator({

  Tab1: {
    screen: TestComp3
  },
  Tab2: {
    screen: TestComp4
  },
  Tab3: {
    screen: TestComp5
  },

})
```

The `FooterTabs` is shown but `TestComp1` and `TestComp2` are also shown everything below one another. How do I fix this? Thanks.

UPDATE 1:

[image]

UPDATE 2:

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  TestComp3: {screen:TestComp1},
  TestComp4: {
    screen:TestComp4,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "TestComp4",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => <MaterialIcons name="accessibility" size={20}/>
      })

  }
```

**UPDATE 3**

I added another `const` for DrawerNavigator and configured it like this:

```
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator({

  First:{
    screen: DrawerScreen1
  },
  Second:{
    screen: DrawerScreen2
  }

},{
  initialRouteName:'First',
  drawerPosition: 'left'
});
```

And included in the app:

```
const MyApp = StackNavigator({
  TestComp1: {screen:TestComp1},
  TestComp2: {screen:TestComp2},
  Tabs: {
     screen: Tabs
  },
  Drawer: {
     screen: Drawer 
  },
}, {
   initialRouteName: "Tabs"
});
```

I'm calling it :

```
<Button
  onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerOpen')}
  title="Show Drawer"
/>
```

OnPress of this button the `DrawerScreen1` is called but as a component, it does not show as a drawer from the left. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try this:

```
const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  TestComp3: {screen:TestComp3},
  TestComp4: {screen:TestComp4}
  TestComp5: {screen:TestComp5}
}); 

const MyApp = StackNavigator({
  TestComp1: {screen:TestComp1},
  TestComp2: {screen:TestComp2},
  Tabs: {
     screen: Tabs
  }
}, {
   initialRouteName: "Tabs"
});
```

and remove `<FooterTabs />` from `TestComp1`

Comment: Thanks. I want the tabs to be visible only on certain components and not all. Plus I wanted the Tabs to be at the footer, How can I do that?

Comment: If you want the tabs to be visible on certain components you can add them to the TabNavigator. If you want them at the footer add tabBarPosition: 'bottom' right next to initialRouteName

Comment: Thanks. One last thing. Where do I add the icons and labels for the tab?

Comment: TestComp3: {
  screen: TestComp3,
  navigationOptions: () => ({
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => <View>...</View>
    })
}

Comment: I imported `import MaterialIcons from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';` and trying what I mentioned in UPDATE 2. But the icon is not showing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Go on and post another question with the code because I can't help like that

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46749137/icons-not-showing-on-tabnavigator

Comment: Alex, I followed your approach and added a DrawerNavigator, but not able to get it to work. Please see UPDATE 3. Can you help here or do I need to create a new thread for it?

Comment: Go on and make a new thread for adding a drawer so that we keep things separate and other people could find them

Comment: thanks Alex. I did : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46775295/nesting-multiple-navigators

Answer (score 0):

Let's see now. What you need is first a `StackNavigator` then inside one of the screens of the `StackNavigator` you need a `TabNavigator`. Right?

The answer to this would be the following: 
For your **index.android.js**:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


import TestComp1 from './src/components/TestComp1'
import TestComp2 from './src/components/TestComp2'

// Don't need to export default here since this is the root component 
// that is registered with AppRegistry and we don't need to import it anywhere.

class myApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <MyApp />
    );
  }
}

// Notice that these two screens will consist the navigation stack.
// Assume, TestComp1 contains our Tabbed layout. 

const MyApp = StackNavigator({
  TestComp1: { screen:TestComp1 }, // This screen will have tabs.
  TestComp2: { screen:TestComp2 }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => myApp);
```

Let's now move on to your `TestComp1`, which is the screen that has your tabs.

**TestComp1**:

```
// ... all imports here.

// This should be your first tab.

class Home extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    // Label for your tab. Can also place a tab icon here.
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
  };

  render() {
    return(
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <View style={styles.mainContent}>
         // This will change your tab to 'Profile'.
         <Button
               onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile', {name: 'Lucy'})}
               title="NewPage"
         />
         </View>
       </View>
     )
   }
 }

 // This can be your second tab and so on. 

 class Profile extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = {
    // Label for your tab.
    tabBarLabel: 'Profile',
  };

    render() {
       return (
         <Text>This is the profile Tab.<Text>
       );
    }
 }

 export default TabNavigator({
   Home: {
      screen: Home,
   },
   Profile: {
     screen: Profile,
   },
 }, { 

   // This will get the tabs to show their labels/icons at the bottom.
   tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

  animationEnabled: true,
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
  },
});
```

So essentially, your `TestComp1` has two components (`Home` and `Profile`) inside it which are both parts of `TabNavigator` so they'll act as tabs. (You don't need to worry about a separate footer component as ReactNavigation places that automatically using your component's `navigationOptions`) We'll be exporting this `TabNavigator` instance that we'll use as an import to `index.android.js` and we'll place this import inside our `StackNavigator` as a screen of the app.

This way you've incorporated `Tabs` as well as `StackNavigator` inside your RN app. Also, `tabBarPosition: 'bottom'` places your tabs at the bottom.
You also no longer to maintain a separate `FooterTabs` component as you can see.

Read up the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab) if you need more clarity or fine-tuning.

Hope I've helped. :)

Comment: Thanks MustanSIR. I went thru this 10 times but getting an error. Updated the question with UPDATE1 for the error.

Comment: Where it says error on line 48, I did exactly as you said. And for error on line 68 I created a const MyApp and did `export default MyApp`

Comment: Nevermind MustanSIR .. I got it .. the previous answer worked. Sorry for the trouble. Thanks a million for helping me tho.

Comment: This must be a typo or something. Might have forgotten a brace somewhere. But glad it worked out for you. You're welcome! Always a pleasure mate! :)