# icons not showing on TabNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Icon not showing in TabNavigator. My code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';

import { StackNavigator,TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';


import TestComp1 from './src/components/TestComp1'
import TestComp2 from './src/components/TestComp2'
import TestComp3 from './src/components/TestComp3'
import TestComp4 from './src/components/TestComp4'
import TestComp5 from './src/components/TestComp5'

export default class myApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (

        <MyApp />

    );
  }
}

const Tabs = TabNavigator({
  TestComp3: {screen:TestComp3},
  TestComp4: {
    screen:TestComp4,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
        title: "TestComp4",
        tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => <View><MaterialIcons name="accessibility" size={20}/></View>
      })
  }
}, { 

  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
    inactiveBackgroundColor: 'green',   //This doesn't work
  },
});

const MyApp = StackNavigator({
  TestComp: {screen:TestComp1},
  TestComp2: {screen:TestComp2},
  Tabs: {
     screen: Tabs
  }
}, {
   initialRouteName: "Tabs"
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

The label is showing for `TestComp4` but the icon is not visible. How can I get the icon to show and change color on click?

The label is showing for `TestComp4` but the icon is not visible. How can I get the icon to show and change color on click?

Comment: Which platform are you testing on?

Comment: I'm testing on Android

Comment: try setting icon View flex to 1 and apply some background color to see if it fills the tab

Comment: `tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'red'}}><MaterialIcons name="accessibility" size={20}/></View>` Did this still nothing. No Icon visible.

Comment: Do you see any background color?

Comment: No Background color either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem, just set `showIcon: true` like so:

```
tabBarOptions: {
   showIcon: true
}
```