# how to integrate stacknavigator in tabnavigator V 5.x

Tags: react-native

**i have this stacknavigator**

```
const Stack= createStackNavigator();
function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen name="Search" component={Search}  options={{title:'Rechercher'}}/>
      <Stack.Screen name="Filmdetail" component={FilmDetail} options={{title:'FilmDetail'}} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

**and this tabnavigator**

```
const MoviesTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator()
  export default function App() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <MoviesTabNavigator.Navigator>
          <MoviesTabNavigator.Screen name="Search" component={MyStack} />
          <MoviesTabNavigator.Screen name="Favorites" component={Favorites} />
        </MoviesTabNavigator.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    )}
```

**the stack navigator don't works anymore when i called it inside tabnavigator,someone can resolve this probleme plz**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735204/integrate-stacknavigator-with-tabnavigator?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You should have just one NavigationContainer above all the Stacks.

AppNavigation:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const AppNavigation = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator 
              initialRouteName="Login"
              screenOptions={({}) => ({
                headerTintColor: 'white',
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: appColors.primary
                }
              })}
            >
              <Stack.Screen 
                  name="FoodCategories" 
                  component={FoodCategories} 
                  options={({}) => ({
                      title: 'Просмотр стола',
                  })}
              />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default AppNavigation
```

Tab navigator:

```
const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

const FoodCategories = () => {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator
            tabBarOptions={{
                indicatorContainerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: appColors.primary,
                },
                activeTintColor: 'white',
                indicatorStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: 'white',
                },
            }}
        >
            <Tab.Screen 
                name="National" 
                component={FoodCategory} 
                options={({}) => ({
                    title: 'нацио...'
                })}
                initialParams={{ category: 'nationalFood' }}
            />
            <Tab.Screen 
                name="FastFood" 
                component={FoodCategory} 
                options={({}) => ({
                    title: 'фастфуд'
                })}
                initialParams={{ category: 'fastFood' }}
            />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    )
}

export default FoodCategories
```